# zf2 smtp - Network is unreachable on cpanel

Tags: php, zend-framework2, smtp, cpanel

I just deployed my website on cpanel. I have used gmail smtp for sending email. It works fine on my local server. But it's giving an error `Network is unreachable` after deploying on cpanel. Server is enabled with smtp protocol. What could be the problem. Is there need to contact hosting provider?

Code for sending mail is

```
        $mail = new Mail\Message();
        $mail->setBody($bodyParts);
        $mail->setFrom($fromAddress, $fromName);
        $mail->setTo($toAddress, $toName);
        $mail->setSubject($subject);


  // setup SMTP options  
  $options = new Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions(array(  
     'name' => 'localhost',  
     'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',  
     'port'=> 587,  
     'connection_class' => 'login',  
     'connection_config' => array(  
     'username' => $fromAddress,  
     'password' => $password,  
      'ssl'=> 'tls',  
     ),  
  ));  

        $transport = new Mail\Transport\Smtp($options);
        $transport->send($mail);
```

Please help. This is first time i'm deploying zf2 on cpanel.

Comment: It obviously looks like _just_ a network problem. Most likely not a fault in your code, rather in configuration or similar.

Comment: @magnilex: thanks,But what could be solution.

Comment: No idea, and I doubt anybody can help you given the way the question is formed. Could it be a full lack of internet connection, a firewall, some typo in your host configuration? Very hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka!!

I just used `ssl` instead of `tls`  and port number `465`

```
  $options = new Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions(array(  
     'name' => 'localhost',  
     'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',  
     'port'=> 465,  
     'connection_class' => 'login',  
     'connection_config' => array(  
     'username' => $fromAddress,  
     'password' => $password,  
      'ssl'=> 'ssl',  
     ),  
  ));
```

Worked perfectly.